# formatting langue arabic to search in text

Tags: php, json, encoding, decode, arabic

I get comment from twitter and facebook

Comment twitter

```
\u0627\u0644\u0627\u062a\u062d\u0627\u062f \u0627\
```

comment from facebook

```
"&#x0645&#x0645&#x0643&#x0646 &#x0633&#x0648&#x0627&#x0644 &#x064a&#x0627 &#x0645&#x0647&#x0646&#x062f&#x0633"
```

and I went search string in my two comment `صباح` if exist or not I use this code but when hi finiched shi return false

```
$texte='blabla arab';//cam from data base
$name="صباح";//my string to search
if (function_exists('grapheme_strpos')) {
            $pos = grapheme_strpos($texte, $name);
        } elseif (function_exists('mb_strpos')) {
            $pos = mb_strpos($texte, $name);
        } else {
            $pos = strpos($texte, $name);
        }
        if ($pos !== false)
            echo 'yes';
```

how can I search my string in all comment cam from facebook and twitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- you should explain what your function do, because may it return false by default or by a logic error

2- use this function 
 preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
and the pattern is "/صباح/"
Like this:

```
       $strings="تم اكل الدجاجه صباح الجمعه";
$pattern="/صباح/";
$replacement="ص";

$search =preg_match($pattern, $strings);
if($search ==1){
 echo "yes! it's here!";
}else{
echo "No!, it's not here!";
}

//if you want to replace the statement you can use this function  
$strings=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement,$strings);
echo $strings;
//The result will be : 
//تم اكل الدجاجه صباح الجمعه
```